# how to config spring actuator Reactive Health Indicators timeout value

Tags: spring

My apps down every morning,from monitor the waiting threads going up from 50 to 200,using this command to dump thread stack:

```
/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jmap -dump:format=b,file=room-service-201911281010.dump 6546
```

I am checked the stack using MAT,and find many thread hang,the part of log like this:

```
Thread Stack

qtp1785687166-3607
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V (Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (LockSupport.java:175)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt()Z (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(I)V (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(I)V (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
  at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await()V (CountDownLatch.java:231)
  at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet()Ljava/lang/Object; (BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:81)
  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block()Ljava/lang/Object; (Mono.java:1494)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans$ReactiveHealthIndicators.lambda$adapt$1(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/ReactiveHealthIndicator;)Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans.java:61)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans$ReactiveHealthIndicators$$Lambda$553.health()Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health()Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health()Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health; (HealthEndpoint.java:50)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SecurityContext;)Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/web/WebEndpointResponse; (HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:54)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor352.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (ReflectionUtils.java:282)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/InvocationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(Lorg/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/InvocationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:294)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:355)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(Lorg/springframework/web/context/request/NativeWebRequest;Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(Lorg/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequest;Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V (ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView; (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView; (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView; (AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (DispatcherServlet.java:942)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (FrameworkServlet.java:897)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:645)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (FrameworkServlet.java:882)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:750)
```

My question is: how to configuration timeout of Reactive Health Indicators? if the /health request no response, return failed or avoid waiting thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to implement custom react health indicator like this:

```
@Component
public class MyReactiveHealthIndicator implements ReactiveHealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Mono<Health> health() {
        return checkDownstreamServiceHealth().onErrorResume(
                ex -> Mono.just(new Health.Builder().down(ex).build())
        );
    }

    private Mono<Health> checkDownstreamServiceHealth() {
        // we could use WebClient to check health reactively
        Health health = new Health.Builder().up().build();
        return Mono.just(health).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Maybe this could help.